# didselectrowatindexpath, Select and Deselect rows in Tableview

Tags: uitableview, row, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I've got a view rows and i want to select a row (or more) by tab in the first time. This is no problem but i like do deselect a row by tab in the second time.
some ideas?
looking forward to here from you.
Regards Hutch

Answer (score 0):

Use this sample code for check mark selection :  https://github.com/vikingosegundo/checkmark/tree/master/Checkmark

Setting the accessory view needs to happen inside the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. When you want to change the accessories from outside, the outside method needs to change the model first to indicate that check marks must be placed in certain cells, and then call reloadData on the UITableView.

One way to store what cells are checked is an array of NSIndexSet objects - one index set per section. In the example below I show code for a single section, but you should get an idea of how to make multiple sections work.

```
// This variable needs to be declared in a place where your data source can get it
NSMutableIndexSet *selected;

// You need to initialize it in the designated initializer, like this:
selected = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if ([selected containsIndex:indexPath.row]) {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    } else {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
    // Do the rest of your code
    return cell;
}
```

Now in the code where you want to set rows selected or unselected you just need to call [selected addIndex:rowToSelect] or [selected removeIndex:rowToUnselect], and call your table's reloadData.